# Model binding TimeSpan from integer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I would like to declare some properties of my View Model of type `TimeSpan` to display the `TotalMinutes` property and bind back to a `TimeSpan`.

I've bound the property without using the strongly-typed helper in order to retrieve the `TotalMinutes` property:

```
<%=Html.TextBox("Interval", Model.Interval.TotalMinutes)%>
```

When the field is bound back to the View Model class it parses the number as a day (1440 mins).

How can I override this behaviour on certain properties (preferably using attributes on the View Model itself)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Writing a custom model binder seems like a good idea here:

```
public class TimeSpanModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName + ".TotalMinutes");
        int totalMinutes;
        if (value != null && int.TryParse(value.AttemptedValue, out totalMinutes))
        {
            return TimeSpan.FromMinutes(totalMinutes);
        }
        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

And registering it in `Application_Start`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(TimeSpan), new TimeSpanModelBinder());
}
```

And finally always prefer strongly typed helpers in your view:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.Interval) %>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
<% } %>
```

And the corresponding editor template (`~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/TimeSpan.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<TimeSpan>" %>
<%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.TotalMinutes) %>
```

Now your controller could be as simple as:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            Interval = TimeSpan.FromDays(1)
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        // The model will be properly bound here
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. It didn't click that it'd be possible to bind to a property of the `TimeSpan` by using the value provider like that. Thanks.